# iPhone Development - sample code LazyTableImages manipulation problem

Tags: iphone

i want to change the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle default style to support one textLabel and two detailTextLabel (it only support one), how do i customzie it ?

LazyTableImages - sample code link:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/index.html

THX :-)

Answer (score 2):

*.i want to change the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle default style to support one textLabel and two detailTextLabel (it only support one), how do i customzie it ?*

Instead of using a pre-built style, add `UILabel` instances as subviews to the cell's `contentView` property. You can add as many labels as you like, wherever you like, looking however you want them, by simply adding subviews to `contentView`.